# Returning a value in a Promise

Tags: javascript, json, promise

I am trying to return a String value to display it in my HTML. In my HTML, I'm using a Text element in a View (similar to a div in React Native) and try to fill it with that that I'm getting from the method `_getCategories`. The problem is that I can't make the method return a String value, since the value is returned inside a Promise.

Now, I'm trying to make this method return a simple String value:

```
    _getCategories = item => {
    const categoryNames = [];
    let fetches = [];
    var allCategories = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < item.categories.length; i++) {
      allCategories = allCategories + item.categories[i] + ',';
    }
    allCategories = allCategories.substring(0, allCategories.length - 1);
    fetches.push(
      fetch(
        'http://54.168.73.151/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?include=' + allCategories
      ).then(response =>
        response.json().then(responseJson => {
          var names = '';
          for (let category of responseJson) {
            names = names + category.name + ', ';
          }
          this.names = String(names.substring(0, names.length - 2));
          console.log(this.names);
          return <Text style={styles.categories}>{this.names}</Text>;
        })
      )
    );
  };
```

I thought this returns the correct value already, but it's not showing in my View. I call the method above as follows:

```html
<View>
      {this._getCategories(item)} //this will be a text element after return
</View>
```

**Edit:**

I have simplified my code by making only one request for all categories together, so it should probably return a the Text object now. Unfortunately, the text is still not showing in my app.

Comment: Promise.all returns another promise, so your overall function is still returning a promise which would resolve to your string.

Comment: Actually, my mistake, it's not returning anything since you don't return Promise.all

Answer (score 0):

First of all return the promise chain from the method:

```
 return Promise.all(fetches).then(res => {
```

but then it still returns a promise resolving somewhen to a text, and there is no way to change that. Instead that text should be part of the components state, so that xou can update the text when the promise resolves:

```
  onComponentDidMount() {
    this._getCategories().then(categories => this.setState({ categories }));
 }
```

And inside `render()` just do:

```
 <div>
  {this.state.categories || <Text>Loading categories</Text>}
 </div>
```

Comment: I updated my code now, but it seems to give me an error on first for loop of the `_getCategories` method, saying that `item.categories` is undefined.

Comment: @MJM yeah well you still have to pass in `item` somehow ... and please don't edit answers into the question, that makes it difficult for further viewers to understand your question ...

Comment: This time I only simplified my code (please see my edit). Do you see why the desired object is not returned properly? I got rid of the Promise.all part now.